# Convert jquery Datetimepicker date to WCF Date

Tags: jquery, json, wcf

I have a js based front end application which communicates with the backend via Jquery.

Backend service is WCF service.

I have a form in which I use jquery date picker.

When I send JSON data to WCF I have to convert date to asp.net date format.

Front end user date selection format : `2014-04-24` or `2014-04-24 23:55`

I should send date as `\/Date(1234567890)\/`

How to do it?

Is there any generic solution for this?

Comment: Which datepicker?....there are two.

Comment: @nFinIt_loop: only two? :)

Comment: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Comment: Is it important which date picker I use? I just want to convert 2014-04-24 to \/Date(1234567890)\/ while form submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for resolve this , you can do :

```
var getTimeWCF= function (dateTimePickerID){
    var dateTimePickerVal = $("#" + dateTimePickerID).val().replace(/-/g, "/");

    var dateTime;
    if (dateTimePickerVal.substr(-2) == "PM") {
        dateTime = new Date(dateTimePickerVal.slice(0, -3) + ":00");
        dateTime.setHours(dateTime.getHours() + 12);
    }
    else if (dateTimePickerVal.substr(-2) == "AM")
        dateTime = new Date(dateTimePickerVal.slice(0, -3) + ":00");
    else
        dateTime = new Date(dateTimePickerVal + ":00");
    return dateTime;
}

var startTimeStr = '\/Date(' + getTimeWCF.getTime() + ')\/';
```